# What word describes the object for which a payment was made?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

This came up with regard to a leasing software application.  Occasionally lump sum payments must be made and the reasons the payments were made - i.e., the object paid for - must be documented.  I don't know what to call those objects.  Payment object sounds more like the currency used for the payment.  Payment Subject is a possibility but seems pretty vague.

Examples of the things that the lump sum payments can cover are Property Tax, Renovations/repairs, property signs.  These could be viewed as additional costs indirectly associated with the leasing arrangement.  That help any? (Thanks for your inputs so far ... altho not quite in synch with the need yet.)

Comment: "Money can be exchanged for *goods and services*." - Homer J. Simpson

Comment: I've seen a lot of invoices over the years which makes me pretty sure such a word doesn't exist in common usage. If you are prepared to relax your single word constraint, I suggest "goods provided", otherwise "merchandise" might be your best bet, even though it doesn't tie itself to a particular payment nearly closely enough.

Comment: Yes, this is a hard one, I think.  But I have this strong instinct that there's a word out there somewhere that fits. I'm okay with more than one word - whatever will have the right denotation.

Comment: There is no special English word for the item that is bought in a commercial transaction. The amount of money transferred is the _cost_ (or _price_), the person giving the money is the _buyer_, the person receiving the money is the _seller_; but the commodity NP that is exchanged for money does not have a specific name in the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf). The best I could come up with in the paper was _commodity_.

Answer (score 1):

Leasing a software application is a  [service](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/SerVice):

> - (Commerce) the supply, installation, or maintenance of goods carried out by a dealer

- The object of payment is the *service* provided regarding the leasing.

(TFD)

Comment: My fault - wasn't clear with my query.  These are additional costs that are only indirectly related to a lease.  The payments might be for property taxes, repairs and/or renovations, property signs - that kind of thing.

Comment: They  appear to be different and unrelated to to each other . Either you mention them singularly is you may refer to them  as *extra* expenses.

Answer (score 1):

I like the general term "items,"

and it might work when combined with:

"listed (items)," "billed ...," "covered ...," "supplemental ...," "additional ...," "extra ...," etc.

For a one-word answer, maybe (to pay the) "[supplementals](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supplementals)" (noun - 4. anything that is supplemental)  might fit, at least in this context.

Comment: Well, we ended up differentiating by the type of payment that would be required for the expense - a lump sum payment - so ended up with Lump Sum Expense Type.  Not ideal probably - but it's done!!  Thanks for your input - greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be exact without an example, which would help greatly, but:

["Purchased"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/purchased?s=t)

Noun 11. something that is purchased or bought.

Trying hard to match to your question, examples could be:

- Reference: The *purchased* [object]
- Financial Statement - "$x.xx - Fee for the *purchased* [object]"

... Or just simply a column heading of 'Purchased' detailing what was obtained for the transactional amount...

Comment: My fault - wasn't very clear in my query.  These are payments for things indirectly related to a lease - like property taxes, renovations/repairs, property signs, etc.  Purchased has some relevance for the signs and perhaps the repairs (a bit of a stretch but kind of works), but doesn't work very well for something like property taxes.   But thanks for the input!

Comment: Ok, so perhaps the generic "Costs" or "Outgoings" for detailing all items of expense, tangible or intangible?

Comment: Well, we ended up differentiating by the type of payment that would be required for the expense - a lump sum payment - so ended up with Lump Sum Expense Type.  Not ideal probably - but it's done!!  Thanks for your input - greatly appreciated!